# Using the (long) out of a function to define another function

Tags: functions, function-construction

It might be a trivial question but I haven't been able to find solution myself. Suppose that I have a calculation whose rather long output that is dependent in some variable e.g. `x`, I want it to be the body of a newly defined function. Schematically, what I would like is

```
In[1]:=  SomethingIsDone[...]
Out[1]:= (...really long expression dependent on x)
In[3]:=  f[x_]:= % ;
```

But the problem is that the above doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you just do `f[x_] = SomethingIsDone[...]`? (Use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`))?

Comment: Because I wanted to be evaluated every time that I call it. Furthermore, I don't want each time that I call the function `f`, to perform the `SomethingIDone[...]`. It's not efficient.

Comment: Actually, maybe you are right. Essentially I want to define it immediately (because of `%`), so the only way to do it is with `Set` and not with `SetDelayed`. Maybe this is the reason that so far it didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed as [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) comments in this case you can just use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) e.g.

```
FlowPolynomial[WheelGraph[9], x];

f[x_] = %;

?f
```

> Global`f
>
> ```
> f[x_] = 254 - 1023 x + 1792 x^2 - 1792 x^3 + 1120 x^4 - 448 x^5 + 112 x^6 - 16 x^7 + x^8
> ```

We could also use [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) and [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) to effect the same thing:

```
FlowPolynomial[WheelGraph[9], x];

g[x_] := Evaluate[%];    (* Evaluate must wrap the entire right hand side *)

?g
```

> Global`g
>
> ```
> g[x_] := 254 - 1023 x + 1792 x^2 - 1792 x^3 + 1120 x^4 - 448 x^5 + 112 x^6 - 16 x^7 + x^8
> ```

Observe that in each case we have created a function that does not call [`FlowPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlowPolynomial.html) when it is evaluated.  Observe also that once defined either function can coexist with a global assignment to `x`:

```
x = "Fail!";  (* try to make the definitions fail *)

f[5]
g[5]
```

> ```
> 6564
>
> 6564
> ```

Comment: I think that `g[x_] := Evaluate[...]` is an abomination that is better not mentioned before teaching the [proper distinction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) between `Set` and `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @Roman My intent was to show the similarity of these constructs as it seems to me the OP was for whatever reason hesitant to use `Set`, perhaps because someone told him to always use `:=` for function definitions.  How would you teach this?

Comment: I'd teach it by making an analogy to something that's already familiar. `SetDelayed` is a [soft link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) and `Set` is a [hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). `SetDelayed` is a cooking recipe and `Set` is an [MRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meal,_Ready-to-Eat). `SetDelayed` is the map, and `Set` is the [territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map–territory_relation). Both are useful; one does not replace the other. Help the student acquire multiple concepts of [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)).